# Use vba to get last cell value in a dynamically populated in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel workbook with 2 sheets 1 & 2. I am running some code to get the Sheet1 populated. Now in Sheet2 B1 cell I want the [Sheet1 last cell value in Column D] + 1.

Can anyone help me code this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will capture the last value in column **D** of **Sheet1**

```
Sub DataCapture()
Dim N As Long, V As Variant
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        V = .Cells(N, "D").Value
    End With
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Value = V
End Sub
```